# JavaScript Promises with setTimeout resolve in sequence

Tags: javascript, promise

I want to print 3 messages in a timed sequence, where each message is displayed after `n` seconds after the previous message is displayed. Requiring to implement this with JavaScript and using Promises, I wrote a function called `printLater` that returns a Promise that leverages `setTimeout` to implement the blocking/waiting mechanism as follows:

```
let printLater = (message, delay) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(message);
            resolve();
        }, delay);        
    })
}
```

Then, I tried using 3 promises to print the messages in sequence and using delays.

```
printLater('first message, after 2 seconds from start of program', 2_000)
    .then(printLater('second message, after 5 seconds after first message is displayed', 5_000))
    .then(printLater('third message, after 1 second after second message is displayed', 1_000));
```

The required output is:

```
first message, after 2 seconds from start of program
second message, after 5 seconds after first message is displayed
third message, after 1 second after second message is displayed
```

But the actual output was:

```
third message, after 1 second after second message is displayed
first message, after 2 seconds from start of program
second message, after 5 seconds after first message is displayed
```

I am trying to understand why the sequence is out of order, given that I am resolving within the function specified for the `setTimeout`.

Comment: `.then` expects a function, not the result of calling a function - simplest fix in this code ... `.then(() => printLater( ........))` ... i.e. `printLater('message', 1000)` calls the function immediately `() => printLater('message', 1000)` creates a function that is called when the previous promise resolves

Comment: it's such a common error to do this in promise chains, yet I can not find a duplicate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create another function to return a wrapper for `printLater()`:

```
const printLaterCallback = (message, delay) =>
    () => printLater(message, delay);
```

Then you can use that in the `.then()` calls:

```
printLater('first message, after 2 seconds from start of program', 2_000)
    .then(printLaterCallback('second message, after 5 seconds after first message is displayed', 5_000))
    .then(printLaterCallback('third message, after 1 second after second message is displayed', 1_000));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi the Promise chaining is in-correct

```
const printLater = (message, delay) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(`*** ${message} ***`);
    resolve();
  }, delay);
});

printLater('first message, after 2 seconds from start of program', 2000)
  .then((data) => {
    printLater('second message, after 5 seconds after first message is displayed', 5000)
      .then((data) => {
        printLater('third message, after 1 second after second message is displayed', 1000).then((data) => {});
      });
  });
```